# Execute the currently selected line in the text editor directly in the terminal in visual studio code

Tags: bash, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Today if I have a command in my text editor in vs code, I have to copy it and paste it into the terminal and then execute it.
Is there is a way or a keyboard shortcut to execute the currently selected line in the text editor directly in the terminal of visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

Currently There is no feature like those.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#interminal)

Define this key binding

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i f5",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.inTerminal",
    "args": {
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": { "text": "${selectedText}" },
      "addCR": true
    }
  }
```

You can add arguments to the [`${selectedText}`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#selectedtext-variable) variable